# BitmapData.draw with different shape

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmapdata

is it possible to change the Rectangle I use as fifth parameter of draw BitmapData class?

```
bitmapData.draw(image,null,null,null,rect,false);
```

I'm trying to draw and save a different shape (with the shape of a particular MovieClip).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the definition for the BitmapData's copyPixels method ([adobe documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#copyPixels%28%29)), you'll see:

> "If you include the alphaBitmap and alphaPoint parameters, you can use
>   a secondary image as an alpha source for the source image. If the
>   source image has alpha data, both sets of alpha data are used to
>   composite pixels from the source image to the destination image. The
>   alphaPoint parameter is the point in the alpha image that corresponds
>   to the upper-left corner of the source rectangle. Any pixels outside
>   the intersection of the source image and alpha image are not copied to
>   the destination image."

You can probably get this to do what you want.